# Difference in horizontal space taken by align* and aligned

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

`\begin{align} A && B \end{align}` and `\[\begin{aligned} A && B \end{aligned}\]` result in different alignments.

`align` seems to use all available space to split two columns,
but `aligned` seems to use only the minimum possible amount of space.

[image]

What is the reason for this disparity, and can one tell `aligned` to use the whole space?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm,paperheight=5cm,margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    Ax = b, && x = A^{-1}b
\end{align*}

\[
    \begin{aligned}
    Ax = b, && x = A^{-1}b
    \end{aligned}  
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `align` is a display construct that always takes the full width of the text block and displays a full equation. `aligned`  sets a vertically aligned subterm at its natural width to take part in a larger equation usually with other terms to its left or right, so isn't what you describe the expected behaviour?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The difference in widths is there by design. Excerpting from section 3.7 of the user guide of the `amsmath` package: "Like `equation`, the multi-equation environments `gather`, `align`, and `alignat` are designed to produce a structure whose width is the full line width. ... But variants `gathered`, `aligned`, and `alignedat` are provided whose total width is the actual width of the contents; thus they can be used as a component in a containing expression." (The user guide goes on to provide examples of "compontents in a containing expression".)

Comment: It makes sense. Is there an option to have `-ed` variants expand in the horizontal space available?

Answer (score 2):

`align` is a display construct that always takes the full width of the text block and displays a full equation. `aligned` sets a vertically aligned subterm at its natural width to take part in a larger equation usually with other terms to its left or right, so like most box constructs, the content is set to its natural width.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's clearer if we add a three column `align`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
Ax &= b, & x &= A^{-1}b
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
Ax &= b, & x &= A^{-1}b & y &= Cz
\end{align*}

\[
\begin{aligned}
Ax &= b, & x &= A^{-1}b
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the blank space is uniformly distributed between columns and margins: `align` measures the column widths, sums them up and sets the space between columns. The equation number will be set in the space at the right or left margin; if you try

```latex
\begin{align}
Ax &= b, & x &= A^{-1}b & y &= Cz
\end{align}
\begin{align*}
Ax &= b, & x &= A^{-1}b & y &= Cz
\end{align*}
```

you'll see that the columns are aligned to each other. However, there is a parameter telling `align` that if the distance from the rightmost (or leftmost column with `leqno`) is less than this amount, the columns will be shifted and the spacing reduced.

The `aligned` environment is a subsidiary one that can be used in any display (or also inline) math environment. Thus it has no notion of line width to be set in. Its columns don't participate in the alignment of outer environments; if the contents of `aligned` is too big, TeX has no way for reducing it, because `aligned` produces a box that's then inserted where requested.

By the way, the standard separation between columns in `aligned` is `\minalignsep` (a parameter also used by `align`), whose default value is 10pt.